# Services unable to start, fixed permissions on registry keys to fix, finding more, root cause?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, services, automated-builds

Having issues with one of our buildfarm Win 7 SP1 machines, being unable to start the firewall service.

The error that it reports is that one of it dependencies was unable to start, which turned out to be the Base filtering engine Service. After searching for a solution I found that giving "NT serives\BFE" account permission to access and modify registry location:
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\BFE fixed the problem, I could now start the service the firewall was being dependent on.

Tee firewall was unable to start still, found the relevant registry key and gave permission to the MpsSvc account, this allowed the service to now start.

Noticed that my network location was not set to Domain or anywhere for that matter and that the "Network Location Awareness" service was also unable to start.  Seems that it is another case of the same issue.

Question is, does anyone know what the root cause of this issue may be? 
 As this is a production build server, thou running Windows 7, we are hesitant to remove the box from the build queue.

Comment: For me it was aggressive malware (I believe a rogue version Avast!). In general uninstalling a third party firewall might have gone awry and failed to restore to default state.